# Why do people from other places understand the questions better than people in the StackExchange communities?

Tags: discussion, comments, questions

Why do people in the Stack Exchange communities have difficulty putting common sense to the questions? and why this does not usually happen in other communities like Reddit or Linuxquestions? just for putting a couple of examples. If your rating to this question is negative, what is your reason?

Comment: Each question I ask ends in an endless discussion tangent to the original theme. Users often ask for implicit precisions and end up complicating any simple question.

Comment: When users ask for more details, do you provide them? Or do you argue that they are not necessary? When you ask a question, you should provide all necessary information to make helping you as easy as possible. Don't make users guess what you need.

Comment: I provide them, but they are not really necessary. Just to give an example, if I ask about a user's experience with a technology, users say that I do not give enough information about the technology, but for that reason my question is addressed to those who know it.

Comment: If we have difficulties understanding a question, 99 out of 100 times the question is at fault. Voting and closing is **the** accepted way **in** our community to handle unclear / off-topic / not needed questions. It takes a few moments to grasp that concept, specially for those with a traditional forum mindset. Anyone who expects an SE site to be a like forum they know, gets a deception if their expectation isn't changed.

Comment: why don't I stumble on "other places" when looking for answers to my questions in Google? And why it is that way too often searches for my questions end on answers posted at that boring, pedantic Stack Exchange

Comment: I lost my keys.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reddit's model is that you say something, other people say things in reply, and when you've read through all the upmodded stuff, you've seen everything funny, everything insightful, everything droll, everything useful, everything amusing, and (often) everything cute and cuddly as well.

Stack Exchange's model is that you *search* for a question, then you *read the answers*, and you're done: you've seen everything that is directly useful for answering your question.

If you didn't find the question you wanted (somewhere around a 5-10% occurrence, generally speaking), you *ask* a *new question*, it gets *clarified* if necessary to boil down to *essential common aspects that others can pick up on*, other people post *answers* to *that question*, still other people *edit* or *comment on* those answers to improve them over time, and when you've read through all the upvoted stuff, you've seen all the good resolutions *to that question*. And … the funny, cute, cuddly, droll, insightful stuff mostly gets quietly stuffed behind the scenes or dropped entirely. Because when you have a question that you want to resolve right now, that stuff just wastes your time, even if it's a fun and interesting waste of time.

The absolutely critical part here is that the experience for the asker was never the top priority. No, there will always be [more sand](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/06/13/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/). It isn't even the answering that's the most critical, although that's pretty high up there. It's the experience for the reader who comes in from search that matters the most. Or, in many cases, the *hundreds*, *thousands*, or *millions* of readers.

Comment: Look, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/434618/how-do-i-sort-mixed-data/434621, be specific does not work, two experienced users do not respond properly, the user expects to use only the sort function, but they include awk and tac.

Comment: @pipeline your specific answer has a drawback that the source data must be modified first. So, while it's answering the question, it might not be the answer that the asker wants.

Comment: @HTTPS Sort does not support regular expressions.

Comment: @pipeline and that's why the other answerers put more efforts to handle the OP's case than just using a simple `sort`.

Comment: @HTTPS, If I need to derive using the definition of the limit, a response using L'Hopital does not work for me, it's the same. Everyone talks about providing clean and precise answers, where is the coherence?

Comment: @pipeline to put it simply, everyone should try their best to solve the asker's requirement as-is, unless the question itself has a problem in which they could provide a better alternative. Regarding the "limit without L'Hospital" example, [there's an example of that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1387726/limit-without-usage-of-derivatives)

Comment: @HTTPS The alternatives, in the best case, should remain as what they are, alternatives, none tried to respond using sort and next the other solution. I know how to solve the limit, it was just an example.

Answer (score 8):

I think users of the Stack Exchange communities apply much more common sense to the Q&A model that they use because they seek to ensure that all questions and answers are as clear as possible to all those who read them.

On other Q&A platforms I find that a more "ask anything, any way you like" approach leads to questions rarely having any value to later readers, and sometimes not even to the original asker.

In each question asked here we look for a single focused question. If we don't find that we ask for clarifications to make the question clearer and better scoped. Clear questions encourage clear answers, anything else often results in convoluted Q&A.

Comment: I think that I can extract the first reason from this question: "You must be completely clear when asking a question, to avoid the use of interpretation". Is my perception correct?

Comment: In each question asked here we look for a single focused question. If we don't find that we ask for clarifications to make the question clearer and better scoped. Clear questions encourage clear answers, anything else often results in convoluted Q&A.